# Knuckle problem

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging

Can anyone help or give me tips? My character model's knuckles look wired when I bend them. The top part is ok, but I want them slightly more pointed. Meanwhile the bottom part just keeps clipping in on itself. I just want them to move like actual knuckles in real life.

[image]

Comment: are you talking about moving them with your armature? maybe change the bones position? or use driver and shapekeys?

Comment: yes i want to move them with my armature i only made the bones invisible to see better in this shot